# Selecting records from two columns of the same table in one subquery

Tags: php, mysql

Back in January, I received some very helpful information about consolidating multiple database queries into one "mega" query, it can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646175/can-select-select-count-and-cross-reference-tables-be-handled-by-just-one-query).

I have expanded on one of the sub queries, this one selects a random photo from the `photos` table for display with each and every project shown on the page. For starters, here is the table from the original post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646175/can-select-select-count-and-cross-reference-tables-be-handled-by-just-one-query):

```
+----------+------------+--------+
| photo_id | project_id | active |
|--------------------------------|
|     1    |     1      |    1   |
|     2    |     1      |    1   | 
|     3    |     1      |    1   |
|     4    |     2      |    1   |
|     5    |     2      |    1   |
|     6    |     2      |    1   |
|     7    |     3      |    1   |
|     8    |     3      |    1   |
|     9    |     3      |    1   |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

This is the subquery recommended to me in the post mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646175/can-select-select-count-and-cross-reference-tables-be-handled-by-just-one-query)

```
(SELECT photo_id FROM Photos 
    where project_id = p.project_id ORDER BY RAND LIMIT 1) as random_photo,
```

I've added additional columns, filename, gallery number to which each image is associated, width of each image and height of each image.

```
+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
| photo_id | filename   project_id | active | gallery | width | height |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1    |  pic1.jpg  |   1      |    1   |   1     | 600   | 400    |
|     2    |  pic2.jpg  |   1      |    1   |   1     | 600   | 400    |
|     3    |  pic3.jpg  |   1      |    1   |   1     | 400   | 600    |
|     4    |  pic4.jpg  |   2      |    1   |   2     | 600   | 400    |
|     5    |  pic5.jpg  |   2      |    1   |   2     | 600   | 400    |
|     6    |  pic6.jpg  |   2      |    1   |   2     | 600   | 400    |
|     7    |  pic7.jpg  |   3      |    1   |   3     | 400   | 600    |
|     8    |  pic8.jpg  |   3      |    1   |   3     | 400   | 600    |
|     9    |  pic9.jpg  |   3      |    1   |   3     | 400   | 600    |
+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+-------+--------+
```

I updated the query to select only images whose width was greater than the height so as to only select a landscape image:

```
(SELECT filename FROM photos
WHERE project_id = p.project_id AND width > height ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as random_photo,
```

And this works as desired.

My new hurdle is wanting to select both the filename AND the associated gallery number for the random image and this is where I'm stuck. In my original post ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646175/can-select-select-count-and-cross-reference-tables-be-handled-by-just-one-query)) there is another subquery that selects a list of tags from another table and it uses `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT` so I tried that, in a number of ways but this is clearly an area I'm in way over my head.

I also tried using `random_photo` within a second subquery like this:

```
(SELECT gallery FROM photos
  WHERE filename = random_photo) as gallery_number,
```

and it didn't work. Ideally, I'd like to retrieve a random photo filename and its associated gallery number in one shot. My apologies if I'm missing something obvious here, and thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple but a bit awkward solution would be:

```
(SELECT Concat(gallery,'___',filename) FROM photos
WHERE project_id = p.project_id AND width > height ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as random_photo
```

If you use above solution you need to split the result at the first occurence of '___' in your php-code.

The more complicated solution would be selecting a random id and than joining the result to the photos-table, but it depends on the other parts of your 'mega-query' how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for this. A couple of questions: what specifically is `'___'` doing, is this the equivalent of ','? Also, what makes this an awkward solution, in your opinion? As for your suggestion on the complicated solution, I agree.

Comment: The ___ is just a seperator so you can split the 2 columns that were merged into one later in your php-code. Your result for a picture pic001.jpg in gallery 2 will be '2___pic001.jpg', all in one column. This is also what is awkward about it, it needs some glue code. It also might cause other issues if you are not careful and your filenames contain '___'. If you split only at the first occurence this should not cause issues and you could even use a shorter seperator like '-', but you need to be aware of it. It works with all filenames because the int gallerynumber is put ahead of the filename.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. I exploded the bound variable in my php code and was able to output the data as desired. Thank you so much!